# How to use win32 pipe on single application

Tags: c++, winapi, pipe

I'm trying to write to a pipe I created locally (in the same application)
At the moment I have this:

```
audioPipe = CreateNamedPipe(
    L"\\\\.\\pipe\\audioPipe", // name of the pipe
    PIPE_ACCESS_OUTBOUND, // 1-way pipe -- send only
    PIPE_TYPE_MESSAGE, // send data as a byte stream
    1, // only allow 1 instance of this pipe
    0, // no outbound buffer
    0, // no inbound buffer
    0, // use default wait time
    NULL // use default security attributes
);
```

I don't know how to actually write data to it. I guess using `WriteFile()` but is there more to it? All examples I read seem to be using a client-server system and I don't need that. I just need to write data to the pipe (so ffmpeg picks it up, hopefully)

Comment: It's a file handle so yes, fundamentally you use `WriteFile`. If nothing's reading from the pipe your call will block when the buffer is full unless you use overlapped I/O. There's various examples in MSDN: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365799%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: Well the pipes are registered in my ffmpeg command so I think it reads from those pipes.

Comment: You call `WriteFile` to feed stuff in, and the thing on the other end calls `ReadFile` to pull that stuff out. That's it.

Comment: I get that. But there is no "other end" except for that I tell ffmpeg to look at those pipes.

Comment: Why are you using a **named** pipe to send data to ffmpeg?  Assuming you are spawning ffmpeg using `CreateProcess()`, you should be using an **anonymous** pipe using `CreatePipe()` instead.  There is an example on MSDN: [Creating a Child Process with Redirected Input and Output](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/ms682499).

Comment: @Remy Are you sure? ffmpeg does indeed support input on named pipes.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: Using a named pipe does not make sense unless ffmpeg is creating its own named pipe for external apps to connect to, or ffmpeg is configured to connect to an external named pipe.  ffmpeg is a command-line app that takes input on stdin and outputs on stdout/stderr, just like any other command-line app does. Using an anonymous pipe is more suitable for that task than using a named pipe. Not to mention that using a named pipe exposes the pipe to outside parties who otherwise should not have access.

Comment: @Remy ffmpeg connects to the pipe that you create. You pass the name of the pipe with the `-i` switch. It's documented. I'm not sure though why anyone would do that rather than pipe in anon pipe using stdin

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: I have never seen ffmpeg used with named pipes before. The documentation merely says that `-i` specifies the input filename (`-stdin` is the default otherwise), but searching around I do see some examples that use a named pipe as the input filename. So be it.  In which case, the OP would need to call both `CreateNamePipe()` and `ConnectNamedPipe()` before than calling `WriteFile()`.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: did you happen to notice whether any of those examples were on Windows?  I checked the documentation too, but I wondered whether that particular clause might only apply to UNIX platforms.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: the command-line documentation says that specifying an input file is mandatory, which implies that you *can't* just pipe the data via standard input.  Whether that is actually true I don't know, but it might explain the decision. :-)

Comment: @Harry Lots of examples with windows named pipes that I can see

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: yes, I did see Windows-oriented examples using named pipe.  And yes, I did red ffmpeg's documentation on piping, and its `pipe:` syntax applies to Unix pipes, not Windows pipes.

Comment: @RemyLebeau `pipe:`? That's new.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-protocols.html#pipe "UNIX pipe access protocol. Allow to read and write from UNIX pipes."

Comment: @Remy Yes. My point is that I don't see why you brought `pipe:` into the discussion.

Answer (score 2):

Based on comments, you are creating a named pipe that the command-line FFMPEG app will connect to.  In order for that to work, you need to do three things:

1. change your call to [`CreateNamedPipe()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365150.aspx) to use `PIPE_TYPE_BYTE` instead of `PIPE_TYPE_MESSAGE`, as you will be streaming raw data live to FFMPEG, not messages.  That will allow FFMPEG to read data from the pipe using whatever arbitrary buffers, etc it wants, as if it were reading from a real file directly.

   ```
   audioPipe = CreateNamedPipe(
       L"\\\\.\\pipe\\audioPipe", // name of the pipe
       PIPE_ACCESS_OUTBOUND, // 1-way pipe -- send only
       PIPE_TYPE_BYTE, // send data as a byte stream
       1, // only allow 1 instance of this pipe
       0, // no outbound buffer
       0, // no inbound buffer
       0, // use default wait time
       NULL // use default security attributes
   );
   ```
2. you need to call [`ConnectNamedPipe()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365146.aspx) to accept a connection from FFMPEG before you can then write data to it.

   ```
   ConnectNamedPipe(audioPipe, NULL);
   ```
3. when running FFMPEG, specify your pipe name as the input filename using the `-i` parameter, eg: `ffmpeg -i \\.\pipe\audioPipe`.

Comment: Can you explain what it means to pass 0 for the buffer sizes? MSDN is, er, lacking, so far as I can tell

Comment: It seems pretty clearly documented to me: "The input and output buffer sizes are advisory. **The actual buffer size reserved for each end of the named pipe is either the system default, the system minimum or maximum, or the specified size rounded up to the next allocation boundary**. The buffer size specified should be small enough that your process will not run out of nonpaged pool, but large enough to accommodate typical requests."  That impies to me that 0 will cause the system default/minimum to be used.

Comment: It would be nice if the docs made it clear how to get default, min or max. In my opinion.

Comment: You should probably pass PIPE_REJECT_REMOTE_CLIENTS too.

Comment: @HarryJohnston: true, though according to the documentation, that flag is only supported on Vista and later.  For XP and earlier, you can deny access to the `NETWORK` ACE on the pipe handle's security descriptor.

Comment: Since XP is now officially past end of life, my policy is to assume that XP support is not required unless the OP specifically says that it is. :-)

Comment: @HarryJohnston: XP may not be supported anymore, but it is still commonly used.  In my programing, I consider XP to be the minimum version that my code must run on unless I know that a customer is not using it anymore.

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing more to this than calling `WriteFile`. You'll also need to call `ConnectNamedPipe` before calling `WriteFile` to wait for the client to connect.

The client reads from the pipe by opening a handle with `CreateFile` and then reading using `ReadFile`.

For a stream of bytes you need `PIPE_TYPE_BYTE`. Are you sure you want to specify 0 for the buffer sizes?

Comment: Can you write to the server end of a named pipe instance before calling ConnectNamedPipe()?

Comment: @HarryJohnston I don't know. Every example I've seen calls `ConnectNamedPipe`.

Comment: Yeah, me too.  The question is a bit vague as to what is actually going wrong, but my guess is that the problem is that the OP isn't calling ConnectNamedPipe.

Comment: `ConnectNamedPipe()` accepts an inbound connection on a listening named pipe, so that would only work if ffmpeg were calling `CreateFile()` to connect to the named pipe. Does ffmpeg actually do that?

Comment: @Remy How else would ffmpeg connect?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: That implies that ffmpeg uses `CreateFile()` and not some other file I/O function, and that it accepts `//<name>/pipe/<name>` as the input value of `-i`.  So be it.

Comment: @HarryJohnston: to answer your question - no, you cannot read/write on the server end of a named pipe until `ConnectNamedPipe()` is called to establish a connection with a client first.